# GitHub GraphQL API returning forbidden when using access token from GithubAuthProvider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, github-graphql, github-app

I'm using GithubAuthProvider with the added scope `repo` to get the user's access token which is later used to access the GitHub GraphQL API (the GitHub App has the permissions for Contents and Metadata set to Read-only).

The problem is when I'm trying to list private repos. The API returns an empty array as if I don't have the required permissions. Moreover, when I try to list branches of a user's repo it returns an error of type `FORBIDDEN`.

Query:

```
query {
    viewer { 
    repository(name: "some-repo") {
      refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 10) {
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "viewer": {
            "repository": {
                "refs": null
            }
        }
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "type": "FORBIDDEN",
            "path": [
                "viewer",
                "repository",
                "refs"
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "saml_failure": false
            },
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 7,
                    "column": 7
                }
            ],
            "message": "Resource not accessible by integration"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I read through the Firebase instructions too fast and created a Github App instead of an OAuth App.

It's now working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub GraphQL API, only scope `repo` may not be enough.

Following are scopes requested for reference. [Authenticating with GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql#authenticating-with-graphql)

```
user
public_repo
repo
repo_deployment
repo:status
read:repo_hook
read:org
read:public_key
read:gpg_key
```

---

`The API returns an empty array as if I don't have the required permissions.`
I wonder whether you are query under the `viewer`. `viewer` can get the private repos he/she **owned**. For repos owned by other people, you can try

```
repository(name: "repo-name", owner: "login") {
  name
}
```

It will return `NOT_FOUND` error if you don't have the required permissions.

---

Your query works fine for me :)